# Removing a blank page from a pdf with itextpdf corrupts my file

Tags: java, itext

I am basing my code from this
https://github.com/Betel-Flowers/BetelFlowers/blob/master/BetelFlowers-ejb/src/main/java/com/betel/flowers/pdf/util/RemoveBlankPageFromPDF.java
or this
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-and-remove-blank-page-in-pdf.html

I am trying to use a byte array as input a byte array as output.

This is my code

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray;

public class RemoveBlankPageFromPDF {

    // value where we can consider that this is a blank image
    // can be much higher or lower depending of what is considered as a blank page
    public static final int BLANK_THRESHOLD = 160;

    public static byte[] removeBlankPdfPages(byte[] fuente) throws IOException, DocumentException{
        PdfReader r = null;
        RandomAccessFileOrArray raf = null;
        Document document = null;
        PdfCopy writer = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream archivoFinal = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            r = new PdfReader(fuente);

            raf = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(fuente);
            document = new Document(r.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
            writer = new PdfCopy(document,archivoFinal);
            document.open();
            PdfImportedPage page = null;

            for (int i = 1; i <= r.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                PdfDictionary pageDict = r.getPageN(i);
                PdfDictionary resDict = (PdfDictionary) pageDict.get(PdfName.RESOURCES);
                boolean noFontsOrImages = true;
                if (resDict != null) {
                    noFontsOrImages = resDict.get(PdfName.FONT) == null
                            && resDict.get(PdfName.XOBJECT) == null;
                }

                if (!noFontsOrImages) {
                    byte bContent[] = r.getPageContent(i, raf);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bs.write(bContent);
                    System.out.println("bs size: " + bs.size());
                    if (bs.size() > BLANK_THRESHOLD) {
                        page = writer.getImportedPage(r, i);
                        writer.addPage(page);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Original: " + fuente.length+ " new: " + archivoFinal.toByteArray().length);
            return archivoFinal.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
            if (raf != null) {
                raf.close();
            }
            if (r != null) {
                r.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my pdf gets corrupted i cannot open it after.

Even with a pdf without spaces I get different sizes, it should be the same

```
Original: 95089 New: 88129
```

That is my output from my las sysout.

I am using itext 2.1.5 and java 1.5 by the way. I cannot upgrade.

Comment: If you took working code from somewhere else, and you are absolutely certain that it worked somewhere else in a more recent version of iText, then it is most likely an issue that is solved by upgrading. If you cannot upgrade then I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways I found an answer. Just in case somebody needs for an older version of itext

```
public static void removeBlankPdfPages(PdfReader r) throws IOException{

        PdfTextExtractor extractor = new PdfTextExtractor(r);


        List<Integer> paginas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= r.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            PdfDictionary pageDict = r.getPageN(i);
            PdfDictionary resDict = (PdfDictionary) pageDict.get(PdfName.RESOURCES);
            boolean noFontsOrImages = true;
            if (resDict != null) {
                noFontsOrImages = resDict.get(PdfName.FONT) == null
                        && resDict.get(PdfName.XOBJECT) == null;
            }

            if (!noFontsOrImages) {
                String textFromPage = extractor.getTextFromPage(i);

                if(textFromPage.length() >50 ){
                    paginas.add(i);
                }
            }

        }
        r.selectPages(paginas);
    }
```

Comment: Using `selectPages` instead of copying the pages is a good approach. But your check for blank pages has a considerable rate of false positives and negatives.

Comment: in my case I new that I only had a few words on the header. You can use if (bs.size() > BLANK_THRESHOLD)  like on the example above

Comment: That's ok for your use case. My remark then is more directed at later readers of your answer so they are warned that they may have to extend your solution somewhat for a saver recognition of empty and non-empty pages.